# Minimist array of strings argument

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can add an array-of-strings argument in [Minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist)?

I want to parse, say, `foos` with a CLI like this:

`$ program foo bar baz`

And have the result be `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`.

The equivalent in Python's `argparse`, for people that are familiar with that, would be `nargs='+'` (or `nargs='*'`).

Comment: What is minimist?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: Please reformulate. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Am I missing something or isn't what you are asking for exactly what is given on the [repo's](https://github.com/substack/minimist) examples?
If I'm missing something, please show a minimal example of your `program` so we have a starting point to help from.